# How can I specify the Jupyter notebook running path?

Tags: 16.04, python, jupyter

I have both Python 2 and 3 installed on my 16.04. However, it seems that Jupyter uses Python 2 as front-end instead of Python 3. [Check out image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVlyU.png).

The problem is that I want to update Jupyter to 6.0 version but I cannot do that because 6.0 does not support 2.7.

Also, when I run `ipython3 notebook` it uses Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
which jupyter-notebook
```

Tells me where my `jupyter` is installed, in my case it's:

```
/home/ravexina/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

#### Which version of python it's using?

Let's run `jupyter notebook`:

```
jupyter notebook
```

You can also run it using:

```
jupyter-notebook
```

then we can use `pgrep` to detect which python version is being used by `jupyter`:

```
pgrep -a jupyter
```

Mine is `python3`:

```
3700 /usr/bin/python3 /home/ravexina/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook
```

---

#### What about screenshot

In your screenshot, what I can see is that your `jupyter` is using `python2` and is running a `python3` kernel, which means you are working with a python3 file however your work is being done by `jupyter` using `python2`.

You might have both versions installed. Anyway my `jupyter` is installed using `pip3` and is up to date, its version is: 4.3.0 and it's the last version, what you are referring is `ipython 6.0.0`.

Anyway, if you don't have `pip3` install it:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

then update it:

```
pip3 install pip --user --upgrade
```

after that install/upgrade `jupyter`:

```
pip3 install jupyter --user --upgrade
```

Now you have last version of `jupyter` and `ipython 6.0.0` as its dependency installed.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Though, `pgrep -a jupyter` returns me `4663 /usr/bin/python /home/vladimir/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook` meaning that it runs under python2. `pip3 install jupyter --user --upgrade` gives me lots of 'Requirement already up-to-date'. So, how can I specify `usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: `whereis jupyter` what is the output of this command?

Comment: `jupyter: /usr/local/bin/jupyter /home/vladimir/.local/bin/jupyter`

Comment: Stop your jupyter that is running, then run : `/usr/local/bin/jupyter` check the version both in jupyter GUI and with `pgrep -a jupyter`.  let me know what it is.

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/jupyter notebook` returns `The version of the notebook server is 5.0.0 and is running on. Python 3.5.2.` `pgrep -a jupyter` returns `29253 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook`

Comment: So I guess you have installed both version, one with regular user privilege the other with root access. use: `pip2 uninstall jupyter` and `sudo pip3 uninstall jupyter` to remove both versions, then follow the answer to install it for your user... it might be helpful.

Comment: SOLVED: to follow the rest of discussion, please read the chat.

Comment: I used the same but there are some message <pre>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
</pre> How to resolve this issue?